# Grep multiple files and output to multiple files in a single command

Tags: grep

I will like to grep a particular pattern from 244 files and generate respective output files for each of them in a single command, how do I do that?

My command for a single file is as follows:

```
grep -v '@SQ' *.sam | grep -v '@HD' cut -f 3 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nrk1 > output_count_file.txt
```

Instead of doing this 244 times for each individual file, how do I do it at once?

Examples of my input files are:

```
A1_001.fastq.sam
A2_001.fastq.sam
B6_001.fastq.sam
```

And I would like to grep some information from these input files into their respective output files e.g.:

```
A1_001.txt
A2_001.txt
B6_001.txt
```

From these output files, I need to grep again to combine information from the output files to another file.

If I do grep for one of these files e.g. A1_001.fastq.sam, I will get the following information:

```
33 chr20:4804587-4804609__hsa_VP64_wgcod_3_27753
33 chr13:113242648-113242670__hsa_VP64_wgcod_2_46197
32 chr8:144718034-144718056__hsa_VP64_wgcod_2_48778
30 chr6:24126264-24126286__hsa_VP64_wgcod_1_71312
```

I need to identify gene names from the second column (e.g. chr20:4804587-4804609) by comparing to a reference file which has the following information:

```
GTGCGCAGCGCTGAGTGTCG    YBEY    NM_001006114_utr5_0_0_chr21_47706267_f;NM_058181_utr5_0_0_chr21_47706267_f  chr21   47706143    47706165
AGCAGGCGGACAGTAGGACG    AUP1    NM_181575_utr5_11_0_chr2_74756757_r chr2    74757053    74757075
TAGGGGCAATGAATGGCGAG    APEX2   NM_001271748_utr5_0_0_chrX_55026756_f;NM_014481_utr5_0_0_chrX_55026756_f    chrX    55026610    55026632
```

Hope my question is not too complicated.

Comment: What are you using your output files for?  You can just grep all the files directly at the same time.  Which your command already does (`*.sam`).  And why are you using multiple "grep" commands in a pipeline?  What is your real desired input and output?  There are probably much easier approaches but it's hard to say when you don't provide sample input and output.

Comment: Given _recent GNU_ awk try `awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"} !/@SQ/&&!/@HD/{n[$3]++} ENDFILE{for(i in n)print n[i],i>FILENAME".out"; delete n}' *.sam`

Comment: You can also use a for loop, google "examples bash for loop files".

Comment: Thanks guys! I edited my question, hopefully it is clearer now? I want to count some lines from my 244 input files and output them into individual .txt files.

Comment: My question remains, for what purpose?  What are you going to do *with* the `.txt` files?  Recreate them every time the `.sam` files are modified?  Use them once and delete them?  Use them for further processing and then produce a summary of *all* results (as I suspect, and which doesn't require making those files in the first place)?  It's not clear what processing you are doing.  Your command for a single file **doesn't work** as your second `grep` ignores its input (missing a pipe).  Even so, since you're passing through `uniq -c`, you should just parse `grep -R whatever *.sam`.

Comment: You are right @Wildcard! I need the output .txt files for downstream processing. I edited my question again. I am a beginner in coding so apparently I can't even ask question properly, please bear with me. If you understand my question and can help me to write a script for that it will be very helpful! As I do not know how to do the step two grep too...

Comment: Getting better.  Is `chr20` a gene name?  Or which part?  I don't see *any* matches between your `grep` output and your reference file.  I really suspect that the whole thing could be handled in Awk directly without any temp files at all.  But it's still hard to say from the given input.  (You didn't show sample intended output.)

Comment: You might want to look over some of the other questions on the site tagged [tag:awk] and see (a) if the answers help you and (b) if you get some clearer idea of how to present your intended input and output so it's clear.  Tip: if you can describe *in English* the logic you are trying to apply to the parsing, it's much easier to answer.

Comment: Gene name is on the second column of the input file e.g. YBEY. You are right, it's not going to be an exact match, I might need to change the format of my reference file or input file. So in my first grep output file, I need to match "chr20:4804587" to "chr21_47706267" from my reference file, of course the two won't match, you know I am talking about the format.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using `find` with the `-exec` flag. This will go through all of the files in the directory, and execute your `grep` individually on each file. You can put a placeholder for the output file to distinguish them.

The command would look something like this:

```
$ find . -iname "*.sam" -exec grep -v '@SQ' {} | grep -v '@HD' cut -f 3 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nrk1 > {}_output_count_file.txt \;
```

Note: I did not test this, so you  will probably need to fix some funkiness with the escapes and placeholders, but it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can make a function that can process a single file:

```
doit() {
  sam=$1
  grep -v '@SQ' "$sam".sam |
    grep -v '@HD' |
    cut -f 3 |
    sort |
    uniq -c |
    sort -nrk1 > "$sam"_count.txt
}
export -f doit

parallel doit {.} ::: *.sam
```